# Show warning when overriding method

Tags: php, inheritance, overriding

I have some abstract class *MyClass* with *foo* method. It is important to call this method from child class when someone iherits from this class and override this methods. So I want to show warning when this situation will happen. But I can't modify child class, because it isn't designed by me. In addition *foo* method can be overriden but not have to.

In code, calling `FirstClass::foo()` should cause warning, but `SecondClass::foo()` not. How can I do this?

```
abstract class MyClass {
    public function foo() {
        // do something important
    }
}

class FirstClass extends MyClass {
    public function foo() {
        // do something special
    }
}

class SecondClass extends MyClass {
    public function foo() {
        parent::foo ();
        // do something special
    }
}
```

Comment: Show warning message please, becouse your current code is right.

Comment: Isn't this an anti-pattern, whereby a parent method is required to be overriden? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super

Comment: In common sense - no. Because you're not able to predict what's going on inside method from outside scope. If it's _you_ who's designing your child classes - then why don't just add direct check? If it isn't you - then you should add some restrictions in question

Comment: Personally I'd use interfaces for this.  If `foo` from `FirstClass` shouldn't be called, it shouldnt be in the class.  Whereas `SecondClass` can implement an interface that requires this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this right. You could add to your abstract class some flag and check it, but it would be wrong.

I propose you to use [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) instead.

```
abstract class MyClass {
    final public function foo() {
        // do something important
        $this->_overridableMethod();
    }

    abstract protected function _overridableMethod();
}

class FirstClass extends MyClass {
    protected function _overridableMethod(){
        // do something special
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done without using `final`? Some of us follow the philosophy that everything should be extendable.

Comment: @Flosculus, what about philosophy: write code without warnings?

Comment: It's great solution. I don't thought about this design pattern. But now, child class have to implement `_overridableMethod()`. In my case someone don't have to implement _foo_ method but if he want it can.

Comment: But I can do non abstract method '_overridableMethod()' in `MyClass`. And now it works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: @sectus And by the way, you think which solution is better in this case: using template method pattern or writing in documentation for my class that must be remembered to call the `foo` method from the base class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is skeleton example of how I would do this:

```
interface VehicleInterface
{
    public function move($x, $y);

    public function refuel($station);
}

interface FlyableInterface
{
    public function takeoff();

    public function land();
}

abstract class AbstractVehicle implements VehicleInterface
{
    /**
     * Implementation to refuel at station
     */
    public function refuel($station)
    {

    }
}

class Car extends AbstractVehicle
{
    /**
     * Implementation to move by following a road.
     */
    public function move($x, $y)
    {

    }
}

class Plane extends AbstractVehicle implements FlyableInterface
{
    /**
     * Implementation to move by means of flying.
     */
    public function move($x, $y)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Override of AbstractVehicle::refuel, landing required first.
     */
    public function refuel($station)
    {
        $this->land();
        parent::refuel($station);
    }

    /**
     * Implementation for plane to take off.
     */
    public function takeoff()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Implementation to land the plane.
     */
    public function land()
    {

    }
}

$vehicles = array(new Car(), new Plane());

$x = '145';
$y = '751';

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {

    if($vehicle instanceof FlyableInterface) {
        $vehicle->takeoff();
        $vehicle->move($x, $y);
        $vehicle->land();
    } else {
        $vehicle->move($x, $y);
    }
}
```

The executing script at the end intends to perform the same task for each vehicle differently depending on the methods each class implements.  Both the plane and the car implement the same `move` method, and they both inherit the the same `refuel` method, however the plane is required to land first.

The executing script will detect what methods are supported by checking if it is an instance of a particular interface.

For an example in practice, Symfony2 class `Command` has a variant called `ContainerAwareCommand`.  By extending this, the framework knows to inject the service container because the supported methods to do so are either inherited or implemented by the child class.